# How to use more than one window manager concurrently?

Tags: xorg, window-manager

I need to install many window managers at the same time and launch any application targeting a specific one of them. For example, I want to launch Chromium in a window manager and then second Chromium instance in another window manager. How can I make this happen?

## Rationale

I have a project idea, described [here](https://github.com/ceremcem/creat-ide), which will act like a window manager for grouping independent applications. In the end, applications have to be launched to use their specific place holder.

Answer (score 0):

Normally all windows managers should be listed on a drop-box on the login screen.

Otherwise,
it used once to work by making custom config files for `xinit` and passing them in as
arguments together with the other arguments for which vt to start on.

Something like this :

```
xinit ~/.xinitrc.i3 -- :0 vt7 &
xinit ~/.xinitrc.xfce -- :1 vt8 &
```

Your version of xinit might differ in parameters.